# Select a listview item programmatically without loading form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to select an item from the `Listview` control without loading the application form.
I just used the following code

```
Listview. Select ()
Listview.item(0).select()
```

But it didn't work. So I would like to know whether this is possible without loading form. And if it possible can someone please help me to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "loading form"?

Comment: If the LV is on the form, and if the form is not loaded, then the ListView is not loaded or available either.  Unless you are using UI controls as variables then get the data from the source (DB, List, Collection etc.)

Comment: "But it didn't work" then exactly what happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
    listView1.Select();
}
```